# No click event when rendering a js.erb partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dom

What happens to the dom when you re-render a partial with `js.erb`? I can no longer get click events.

Based on [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy), I have followed it to re-render a `js.erb` partial which works fine. When I click the "cat.name" button (on linked page), and on that page is another button that I'm listening for click events but not working.

The run down:

On index page, click event works. When I make the request for `from_category`, no more click event. So what really happen?

Html:

```
<button id="test" value="ok">click</button>
```

JS:

```
$( "#test" ).on("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You click events don't bind to the new dom elements you should use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bubble the events to the newly created dom elements

```
$('body').on('click input keypress','.the_dynamic_element',function(){

});
```

Comment: So basically I should have this `$( "#test" ).on("click", "button", function(e) {...})`? Does not work.

Comment: the nearest element that is not added by the ajax

Answer (score 1):

No need to bind the event on body you can use this format to bind the event to the selector

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
});
```